# What is the suitable solution to enforce polymorphysm when using interfaces as superclass

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, polymorphism

I recently started learning Java programming language and I wanted to test my polymorphism knowledge on an application simulating smart devices.

I created an Interface named Os, the main job of this interface is to dictate to its inheritors what they should implement for themselves.

```
public interface Os {
   public ArrayList<App> getApps(); 
   public void installApps(Collection<App> apps);
}
```

then I created two classes one for android and another for ios.
I also created an interface named App and two classes which inherit from it named AndroidApp and IosApp.

Now I want to use polymorphysm as much as I can but I am having trouble understanding which goes where. I wanted Android os to have a private collection for itself which only accepts type of AndroidApp like this
`ArrayList<AndroidApp>`
but I figured since I want to implement getApps method of the interface I can not put the return type of that method in the interface so I needed something upper in the hierarchy and, so instead I changed my private list for android os to `ArrayList<App>`.

I have a method which is in charge of installing apps on the Osez that I have.

```
public class Android implements Os {
    private ArrayList<App> androidApps;
    public void installApps(Collection<App> apps) {
      //I want to only install Android apps(adding them to my private collection
        for (App app : apps) {
            if(app instanceof AndroidApp){
              System.out.println("installing android app ... "   +app.getAppName()+" installed!");
                androidApps.add(app);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(app.getAppName()+" is not an android app!");
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before getApps is in charge of giving me back the installed apps on any Os that I choose.

This is a conceptual question. I am having trouble figuring out if I should have used a more specific collection for Android and Ios.
Like this

```
public class AndroidOs{
    private Collection<AndroidApp> androidApps;
}
```

instead of using

```
public class AndroidOs{
    private Collection<App> androidApps;
}
```

but if I would have used the first private collection my interface is going to lose its purpose of being a general interface for both operation systems because when I try to implement `getApps` for android I can not cast the `ArrayList<AndroidApp>` to `ArrayList<App>`.

Sorry if my question was kind of vague but I tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Down-voted because you indicated you are trying to learn polymorphism but under my answer, you commented that you already know polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [generic type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

```
public interface Os<A extends App> {
   List<A> getApps(); 
   void installApps(Collection<A> apps);
}

public class Android implements Os<AndroidApp> {
    private ArrayList<AndroidApp> androidApps;

    @Override
    public void installApps(Collection<AndroidApp> apps) {
        for (AndroidApp app : apps) {
            System.out.println("installing android app ... "   +app.getAppName()+" installed!");
            androidApps.add(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes !!! I completely forgot about this ! Well Lynda forgot about this. I wanna thank your for this solution to my problem. I hope the pattern I am going for is the suitable one.

Comment: I think it is the same writing "App" or "A extends App". Because they will be all "App"s here. Just creates a higher consistency and you are sure that your AndroidOS will only have AndroidApp s. But you have to put AndroidApp s to your Collection instead of filling with App s and filtering them when needed. Use which one is more suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You say that you want to use polymorphism as much as you can but in the software development none of the methods or design patterns are used as much as they could; they are used "**when they are needed**". So you must use all the techniques and stuff when you need. But anyway I just understand you want to learn polymorphism here.

The definition:

> Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. The
>   most common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class
>   reference is used to refer to a child class object.
>   (Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)

Now a real sample from development world: You have got an animals "list" object and you want to keep all of the animals inside a cache list where you have fetched from a database and represent at some UI but there are softly different things per animal type when showing them. So here you HAVE TO use polymorphism to keep all object at one place and also assign properties according to their slight changes.

```
Base interface: Animal-->eat();feet();
Animal1: Elephant :: Animal-->eat(){print "grass"};feet(){print "four feet"};
Animal2: Eagle :: Animal-->eat(){print "meat"};feet(){print "two feet"};
```

Create objects

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Elephant());
animals.add(new Eagle());
```

Now you have your elephant and eagle in one list and do whatever you want by checking the type or just a field per item.

**Your question details:**

```
Base interface: OS
public interface Os {
   public ArrayList<App> getApps(); 
   public void installApps(Collection<App> apps);
}

os1: Android :: OS
os2: IOs :: OS

Base interface: App
public interface App {
   public int getVersion();
}

app1: AndroidApp :: App
app2: IOsApp:: App
```

Question number one: Is this structure right?

Answer: Yes, for a specific reason. Let's say you got a quite huge app being developed by a couple of developers. You are the dev. lead and decide the structures and techs on this project and you want the all OSes be structured like your interface: Let's say we want to add blackberry, then we are going to derive our BlacberryOS from OS and BlackberryApp apps from App. This will provide you the consistency of every new OS that are added to the system and this is true.

Question number two: Is there a better way?

Answer: Ther are always better ways. Here, you are saying that you are new to Java PL development and want to learn polymorphism. So I advice you to try like I explained: Create a list of OSes and add there AndroidOS, OIS, Blackberyy etc.. and while iterating over the list, print specific things according to the types of it so there you will understand what polymorphism really is end why it is needed.

By providing the method-overwrites you will see that printing properties specific to sub-types is really easy and structured with polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to the Java World, but I worked on structured programming projects and the concept of polymorphism is somewhat new to me.

Comment: Ah sorry read that wrong. Now fixing that part. Is my answer good for your question?

Comment: no problem. Yes thank you for your efforts, but I was already familiar with polymorphysm concept, all I wanted to know was whether I am using it correctly or not, and the guy suggested generic list nailed it.

Comment: Yes it is a very good method to use them but in that way, your Collection will only contain AndroidApp instead of App. You will either filter them outside of that method before use or at that method (installApps). If you filter them in that method I think code readability would increase and related methods are placed in the correct place. The generic class types are more useful when you got methods for almost any kinds of classes, not for the ones specifically extended from some classes.